# Don't want to perform action on the button multiple times in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, I am learning it from w3schools while practicing the below example, I don't understand why the function is returning as many times I clicked the button and I don't what that action to be done that means if once I click the button the new text/Html has to be changed in the dom but if again I click the button then no action to be performed. How can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery HTML</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#test1").text(function(i, origText) {
                return "Old text : " + origText + "New text : Hello World (index: " + i + ")";
            });
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            $("#test2").html(function(i, origText) {
                return "Old HTML: " + origText + "New HTML : Hello World (index: " + i + ")";
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
  <p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
  <button id="btn1">show old/new text</button>
  <button id="btn2">show old/new html</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appending the text because the `origText` argument holds the current value. As such you append `New text...` to whatever content is already there on every event.

To fix this you can just not use that argument, and set the value to return the same string every time the event fires:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#test1").text(function(i) {
      return 'New text : Hello World (index: ' + i + ')';
    });
  });
  
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#test2").html(function(i) {
      return 'New HTML : Hello World (index: ' + i + ')';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<button id="btn1">show old/new text</button>
<button id="btn2">show old/new html</button>
```

I'd also suggest not using W3Schools for anything as their content is often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any. I tend to use the documentation as a reference. Most method names are self-explanatory: https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

> I click the button [again] then no action to be performed

taking this literally (rather than the other answer which alternatively takes it as "it gives the same value")

You can use `.one` so that the "click" event only occurs once:

```js
 $("#btn").one("click", function() {
     console.log("button clicked");
     $("#text").text("after");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='text'>before</div>
<button type='button' id='btn'>click</button>
```

Alternatively, you can turn off the click event, which has the same effect

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
     console.log("button clicked");
     $(this).off("click");
     $("#text").text("after");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='text'>before</div>
<button type='button' id='btn'>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `$("#btn1").one('click', function(){...` can solve your problem